# Can s3cmd be used to download a file and upload to s3 without storing locally?

Tags: s3cmd

I'd like to do something like the following but it doesn't work:

wget http://www.blob.com/file | s3cmd put s3://mybucket/file

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Cannot speak for `s3cmd` but its definitely possible.

You can use https://github.com/minio/mc . Minio Client aka `mc` is written in Golang, released under Apache License Version 2.

It implements `mc pipe` command for users to stream data directly to Amazon S3 from an incoming data on a pipe/os.stdin.  `mc pipe` can also pipe to multiple destinations in parallel. Internally mc pipe streams the output and does multipart upload in parallel.

```
$ mc pipe
NAME:
   mc pipe - Write contents of stdin to files. Pipe is the opposite of cat command.

$ mc cat
NAME:
   mc cat - Display contents of a file.
```

## Example

```
#!/bin/bash

mc cat https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/1.txt | mc pipe https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mywestbucket/1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question regarding `s3cmd`: No, it can not (currently) [read from `STDIN`](https://www.vennedey.net/blog/1-Pipe-data-from-STDIN-to-Amazon-S3).

It [does support multi-part-upload](https://s3tools.org/kb/item13.htm) and also [streams **to** `STDIN`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744257/is-it-possible-to-pipe-from-stdin-to-gzip), but apparently not the other way around.

Piping output from `s3cmd` works like this:

`s3cmd get s3://my-bucket/some_key - | gpg -d | tar -g /dev/null -C / -xvj`

*Please be aware that there may be an issue with streaming `gzip` files: [https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/811](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/811_)*